# Error with path of FOSJsRoutingBundle in KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony-2.3

I'm using version 2.3 of Symfony and KnpSnappyBudle to generate templates Twig HTML to PDF. I had a problem adding images, but I saw that the solution online using the URL request is solved. 
Example: `src = "{{app.request.scheme ~ ': //' ~  app.request.httpHost ~ asset ('img / logo.png')}}"`

Now I have a problem that I can not solve. I am using FOSJsRoutingBundle to generate routes and the template that convert to pdf with KnpSnappyBundle I have the following:

```
     <Script type = "text / javascript" src = "{{path ('fos_js_routing_js', {" callback ":" fos.Router.setData "})}}"> </ script>
```

With this line to generate the pdf gives me the following error (the same mistake that gave me the images before using routes on request):

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
[=======> ] 13%
[==========> ] 18%
[==========================> ] 44%
[============================> ] 47%
[==============================> ] 50%
[==============================> ] 50%
[===========================================> ] 73%
[==============================================> ] 78%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
"stdout: ""
command: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --page-size 'A4' --viewport-size '‘1024x768’' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d24a82.40556276.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d25009.94614572.pdf'.
```

Is there any way to change that to work? I'm starting on this, so I would appreciate your help.